# Error: argument of type char* is incompatible with parameter of type LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
char* file="d:/tester";
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
hFind = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);  // line of error says argument of type char* is incompatible with parameter of type LPCWSTR
}
```

I can't understand the error.What is it and how can I solve the error?

*I am making a console app and need to check if files are in there in the directory .*

Comment: Have you tried `(LPCWSTR)(&FindFileData)` (or any C++ style cast)?

Comment: Does it give you the error without using the reference? (file, FindFileData)

Comment: @ iammilind Yes it works after casting like this : `(LPCWSTR)file`  But what is LPCWSTR

Comment: @iammilind: Are you serious about casting a `char*` into `LPCWSTR`?

Comment: @sharptooth, years back when I was learning VC++ GUI, I saw such casting in many articles. In fact that's the way it was happening. I don't remember now where I saw that. But it was harmless.

Comment: @ sharptooth what is the harm ?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: Well, `char*` is a "one byte per character array", `LPCWSTR` is a "two bytes per character array". Casting effectively tells the compiler "shut up, I insist that this `char*` is in fact a `LPCWSTR`" - at best it won't work at worst you program will have a nasty bug.

Comment: @iammilind: Having lots of C-style casts is indeed not uncommon in most articles, but it doesn't mean one should do the same. It is not harmless in this case.

Comment: My guess is that you actually saw those articles casting `char*` into `LPCSTR`, **without the `W`**. The `W` indicates a *wide* string, composed of `wchar_t`, rather than `char`. But this is definitely a reason why C-style casts are to be avoided in C++. **And** you should **always** use wide strings for new Windows development. So forget that `char*` or `LPCSTR` even exists. Always use `LPCWSTR` and `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling function that expects wide character string (`FindFirstFileW`). You either change file to use `wchar_t* file = L"d:\\tester";` or use an ASCII version of the function `FindFirstFileA`.

Comment: Yes it works.But i could not understand what did i do .Can you elaborate your answer please.

Comment: When Windows added support for Unicode, they decided to create two versions for many functions with W and A at the end, so function name is mapped to one of them depending on Unicode settings.

Answer (score 4):

the type `LPCWSTR` is a const pointer to wide char

the `file` in `char* file="d:/tester";` is a pointer to an ordinary char

Ordinary char usually uses 1 byte of memory, while wide char usually uses 2 bytes. What will happen if the file name contains cyrillic or japanese letters? You will not be able to open it without specifying the encoding. Windows API accepts wide chars to `FindFirstFile` function, because file name can be in a unicode. So, if you write `L"foo_bar"` the compiler will interpret it as wide character string. Therefore you can write `wchar_t* file = L"d:\\tester";` to match parameter types, so compilation will be successful.

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling with UNICODE defined and yet passing an ANSI string as your first parameter. Replace your line that beings char * with

TCHAR *file=TEXT("d:\tester");

and things should be fine.

Martyn

Comment: You need to understand more about how the Windows API works with Unicode. There is a good overview here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374089(v=VS.85).aspx and the specific reference section on the TEXT macro is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374086(v=VS.85).aspx

The answer using wchar_t is not correct because the rest of your code calls FindFirstFile which is a macro that autoswitches A/W and hence requires the TEXT macro. 

Martyn